# How to display image url from website sub pages using php code

Tags: php, image, url

I am using below mentioned php code to display images from webpages.Below mentioned code is able to display image url from main page but unable to display image urls from sub pages.

```
enter code here

<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$target_url = "http://fffmovieposters.com/";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($target_url);
foreach($html->find('img') as $img)
{
echo $img->src."<br />";
echo $img."<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `$target_url` to sub page? Like `$target_url = "http://fffmovieposters.com/about"` ?

Comment: use http path for all images..it will work

Comment: actually i don't have url of all sub links.Is it not possible that using code i will be able to get all sub link images? means code will automatically check all sub links under this domain.

Answer (score 1):

If by sub-page you mean a page that `http://fffmovieposters.com` is linking to, then of course that script won't show any of those since you're not loading those pages.

You basically have to write a spider that not only finds images, but also anchor tags and then repeats the process for those links. Just remember to add some filters so that you don't process pages more than once or start processing the entire internet by following external links.

**Pseudo'ish code**

```
$todo = ['http://fffmovieposters.com'];
$done = [];
$images = [];

while( ! empty($todo))
    $link = array_shift($todo);
    $done[] = $link;
    $html = get html;
    $images += find <img> tags
    $newLinks = find <a> tags
    remove all external links and all links already in $done from $newLinks
    $todo += $newLinks;
```

Or something like that...

Comment: Is possible please modify my code for sub links/sub pages requirement,actually i require url of .jpg images exist on whole website.

Comment: @tahirmehmood I gave you some pesudo code now, but you need to write your code yourself. I have my own job where I need to write code. You can check out my blog post on loading images (which takes relative URLs and such into account here: http://www.geekality.net/?p=1585, but you need to adjust it to process a full website recursively yourself.

Comment: thanks--please add in my existing code so that i will be able to test it on my server.

Comment: @tahirmehmood There is no code to test on your server until you have written that code. Pseudo code = rough draft of what you need to do, not actual code that works. You're probably paid to solve the problem you're trying to solve, so do your job and write the code :)

Comment: there is no payment involve in this case actually this is initial learn phase in start of my php scripting.

Comment: @tahirmehmood Then you should *definitely* do it yourself to learn! You don't learn anything by having others do your scripting for you :) Do it one step at a time, solve each problem. It's not a very difficult problem.

Comment: ok--thanks for you advise.Your above mentioned code is for php as there are many syntax error in this code.

Comment: @tahirmehmood Only some of it is actual PHP, most is pseudo code. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode